# how understand one result set is subset of another in twomysql select result set?

Tags: mysql, select

I've 2 mysql select statements, suppose these are my queries & their result :

Statement 1 :

> select id from a

which returns this result set : { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }

Statement 2 :

> select id from b

which returns this result set : { 3, 5, 10 }

I want to write a query which determines whether resultset1 contains all records of resultset2 or not. I think needs a simple query, any suggestion ???

Comment: So to check I understand your question correctly: You want a query that returns a single value, either 0 or 1? And in your example you want it to return 1, because in this case the result of query 1 contains all the values from query 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this:

```
select count( case when a.id = b.id then a.id end ) = count(b.id) 
    as is_a_containing_all_b
from b
left join a using(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `in ( <subselect> )` and `not in ( <subselect> )` clauses to do this.

```
select 'inset' , a.id as IN_SET 
  from a 
 where a.id in (select b.id from b) 
union
select 'not inset' , a.id as IN_SET 
  from a 
 where a.id not in (select b.id from b)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to create `b LEFT JOIN a` and check if any row exists where the join fails:

```
SELECT NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT b.id
   FROM b
   LEFT JOIN a
   ON a.id = b.id
   WHERE a.id IS NULL
) AS T1
```

Result:

```
1
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO a (id) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);

CREATE TABLE b (id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (3),(5),(10);
```